# Turn off AwaysOn in Azure Function to get a free App Service Plan?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

I made an Azure function, which made me an App Service Plan. I noticed my bill started going up, so I tried to change my app service plan to the free pricing tier. It rejected with the reason:

> Cannot update the site 'my-site' because it uses AlwaysOn feature which is not allowed in the target compute mode.

Is there a way I can turn off the AlwaysOn feature of my Azure Function so I can change my app service plan to the free tier?

Comment: From portal, you should be able to browse to your function app -> general settings and disable the AlwaysOn.   If still can't find, try with https://resources.azure.com (see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-resource-explorer-a-new-tool-to-discover-the-azure-api/).

Comment: You should have created a function app on a consumption plan ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the Overview page click on configuration and then click on general settings

[image: Overview]

[image: General settings]

Comment: How do you do this in the currrent azure portal?  I don't see configuration option in app service plan overview page.

Answer (score 2):

@Jeremy : given answer is correct. You won't find this setting in the overview page of you app service plan. Instead go to the actual web app/function app > Select "Configuration" (under the Settings section) > "General Settings". You can find and toggle the "Always On" option there

Comment: Note this is only true if you're using the Basic/Standard/Premium App Service plan to run your AzFunc. If you're using Free/Shared or Consumption, then setting Always On is not available (and is on by default)